# How to retrieve the APIKEY for a Compose database instance on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, compose-db

The Compose [documentation](https://help.compose.com/v2.0/docs/managing-backups-via-the-compose-api) describes how a backup can be initiated:

```
export APIKEY=your_apikey_here
export DEPLOYMENT=your_deployment_id

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $APIKEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.compose.io/2016-07/deployments/${DEPLOYMENT}/backups"
```

I would like to execute this API call against a 'Standard' Compose database running on Bluemix (not Compose Enterprise).

The `DEPLOYMENT_ID` is available in the VCAP_SERVICES json, but I can't find the `APIKEY` - where can I find this?

Comment: This seems oddly vendor specific for a public question. Have you not approached either Bluemix or Compose's support channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you refer to are specifically for the Compose native API and not for the IBM Cloud (now) Compose API.

The IBM Cloud Compose API arrived in public in November - https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/opening-the-compose-api-on-the-ibm-cloud/.

Consult https://www.compose.com/articles/the-ibm-cloud-compose-api/ for details on how to use it and where to retrieve appropriate IBM Cloud API keys, which IBM Cloud endpoints to use and what Compose API calls are available (Spoiler: Yes, you can do on demand backups from there).